# Android: ListView conditional scrolling

Tags: android

I have a 2 pane layout. On the left is a `ListView`, on the rights some content linked with the list. The content is scrollable.
If content moves forward, I want the list to go forward only if this item is not yet displayed. This prevents that the list has to update on every content change. I also want the list to go ahead one full page.
Is there something like

```
listView.isThisElementCurrentlyShown(int nr)
```

and

```
listView.moveAheadOnePage(int direction)
```

?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: smoothScrollTo()? Here are all the functions avaiable for listview: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of `isThisElementCurrentlyShown(Element e)`:

```
    public boolean isThisElementCurrentlyShown(Element e){
                ListView lv = getListView();
                int start = lv.getFirstVisiblePosition();
                for(int i=start, j=lv.getLastVisiblePosition();i<=j;i++){
                    if(e==lv.getItemAtPosition(i)){
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
}
```

This will tell you whether the element is visible or not.

For the `moveAheadOnePage` you should be able to use listview's built in functions `getFirstVisiblePosition()` and `getLastVisiblePosition()` to calculate the number of rows visible on that device, then advance the listview ahead that many positions.  Something like this pseudocode (you will have to write this one):

```
public void moveAheadOnePage(int direction){//direction: 0-up, 1-down
    int numVisibleRows = getLastVisiblePosition() - getFirstVisiblePosition();
    this.setSelected(currentSelection + numVisibleRows) // +/- depending on direction
}
```

Mind you these are both expensive calls to make while scrolling through a listview, so you will definitely have to implement wisely~

EDIT: Updated code to include `return false`